# Why aren't my breakpoints being hit for my MarshalByRefObject object?

Tags: c#, debugging, iis, .net-remoting

I'm working in IIS 7.0 on Windows 7. I have a class that derives from MarshallByRefObject. When I construct it's giving me my proxy as it should. I have breakpoints set on the object in question. The class is called from another class running from a GET request being handled by IIS. The caller is running on the IIS worker process (w3wp.exe) and its breakpoints are being hit (i.e. I have breakpoints at both [1] and [2], but only the breakpoints at [1] are getting hit).

```
public class Caller
{
    public void Process()
    {
        var callee = new Callee();
        callee.Method(); // [1]
    }
}

public class Callee : MarshallByRefObject
{
    public void Method()
    {
        DoSomething(); // [2]
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is callee running? Is your debugger attached to that process, too? Did you get any error/warning messages about symbols not being loaded?

Comment: Is Callee is in a different process/app?

Comment: @leppie I don't believe so. They should be in the same process.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I believe that both classes are running in the IIS worker process (w3wp)

Comment: Usually when there is strangeness, there is a mistaken assumption.  I'm guessing my answer below ends up proving correct.  Can you show us the actual creation of the MBRO?  If you aren't crossing process boundaries (or at least AppDomain boundaries), what exactly are you using an MBRO for?

Comment: @RussellMcClure What I have above is how it's constructed and called. No craziness there. It's Caller that's dynamically loaded.

Comment: Then why is it an MBRO?  And why do you have the .net-remoting tag on your question?

Comment: @RussellMcClure  It is MBRO and the object is used in a .Net Remoting way, but not in this particular location as far as I can tell.

Comment: If that is true then the debugger shouldn't have any problem stopping at [2] if it can stop at [1].  Since the debugger can't, I'm guessing [2] is actually in a different process.  But I can't prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the method on your MBR doesn't execute in the same process ( I'm assuming you are not just crossing AppDomains inside a single process ).  You only have reference to a proxy but the method body doesn't actually execute in the callers AppDomain.

Check to see that you're attached to the service processes that it could potentially be.

Comment: Well that depends on your MBRO creation code.  An MBRO is used to cross AppDomain boundaries either within the same process or across processes.

Comment: @RusselMcClure The code above is the exact same code in question except the names of Caller and Callee are clearly made up. But there's no additional craziness. It just constructs the object and then calls the method.

Comment: There has to be some craziness, otherwise the debugger would easily stop on [2] if it can stop on [1] and it's all executing in a single AppDomain as you say.  Well, if I turn out to be right, drop by and take away my -1.

Comment: It wasn't my -1. It was someone else's. But I gave you a +1 and marked you correct for your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

How do you reference the Callee? I assume they are not in the same project, so check that:

- Both projects are built properly
- There is only one instance of the Callee project executable (dll or exe) on your system, including GAC. You should use GacUtil to check if your assembly is in GAC (google about it).
- Callee project is built in debug mode.

Comment: Why does the DLL have to be in the GAC for this kind of debugging to work? The Callee code is running and Visual Studio isn't telling me it won't get hit. It just doesn't hit.

Comment: No, it should NOT be in GAC. But if it is in GAC, it will be loaded from there and your debugger will miss it. So what I mean is: make sure your assembly is NOT in GAC, but is loaded from the location where debugger can find it. Btw, if it is not signed, it cannot have gone to GAC.

Comment: Oo, I just read 'The Callee code is running': are those both in separate processes? In that case, are both running in the same debugger? My notes a) to c) still apply in this case, but in addition, do run them in the same debugger.

Comment: They're actually in the same process this time. The Callee gets used in other processes as well, but the DLL that the Callee is in is directly referenced by the caller. That said, the classes are dynamically loaded via reflection.

Comment: I guessed you are dynamically loading it - this is the mother of all debugging issues. Check those a-c, but there could be other issues. You can also do a MessageBox.Show() and ask for the location of own assembly, to see where it is...